# Executing a shared object file

Tags: java, android, runtime

I have licpuminer.so in the res/raw folder.

```
String libFile = "android.resource://com.example.suraj.myapplication/raw";
String url = "abc.com";
String user = "user";
String password = "pass";
Boolean isNeon = false;

try {
    String str = libFile;
    str = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(isNeon ? new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(str)).append("/libcpuminerNEON.so ").toString() : new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(str)).append("/libcpuminer.so ").toString())).append("--algo=scrypt  -o ").append(url).append(" -u ").append(user).append(" -p ").append(password).append(" -t ").append(thread).toString();
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str, new String[]{"LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" + libFile + ":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"}, new File(libFile));
            Log.e("errorE", str);
            Log.e("errorE", process.getClass().getName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("errorE", "error");
        }
    }
```

I am getting

> java.io.IOException: Error running exec() Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Comment: Indeed. No such file on the file system. Correct exception.

Comment: @greenapps, I have given the libpath and file is present in the res/raw folder. If it is not the correct way. Where should I put the file so that I can execute it.

Comment: Put files on the file system.

Comment: can't we keep it in the res/raw folder as suggested by google.

Comment: I'm not aware that google suggests such in this context. And i do not understand what you mean. Of course you can have files as resource in res/raw. As much as you want.

Comment: I want to execute my file which is in the res/raw folder. How can I do that ?

Comment: One cannot execute files in resources. They have to be on the file system. I said that before.

Comment: They have to be on the file system ? I need to put them in the lib directory ?

Comment: Which lib directory on your Android device file system are you talking about? I think if you just put them on external storage you can execute them.

Comment: I am creating an app and I want to execute this file. I can't keep it in the external storage. I have to ship it with the application and keep it inside the application.

Comment: Yes you ship the .so as resource in your application. Thats clear. Nobody suggested you should do different.

Comment: `I can't keep it in the external storage. `. ??? That is a nonsense statement. As there is no external storage before shipping.

Comment: Resources are not files. They are resources.